# Linux : See CPU usage by a process for the last second

Tags: linux, process, monitoring, ps

```
vmstat 1
```

Above will print virtual memory statistics each seconds. It will also show the CPU utilization for last second.

I have a web server at hand which runs httpd and MySQL. I need to find how much CPU httpd consumed in last second. Like vmstat particularly for httpd.

I tried this :

```
ps -e -o %mem,%cpu,cmd | grep mysql | awk '{memory+=$1;cpu+=$2} END {print memory,cpu}'
```

But it will show me the ratio of CPU used since the start of the process.

So, with above, if my process caused a spike and then went to sleep for long time, I won't know it. It's like windows process manager, which shows which process is using how much CPU. I hope I am making my question understandable. I will clarify if anything is missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `top -b -d 1` to achieve that for CPU usage.  `top` displays process CPU usage relative to the last output.

Answer (score 0):

cgroups has a whole accounting suite to play with and is lightweight.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/cpuacct.txt

Comment: Link is dead and answer is a link only.